# nil? method returns true even if the object is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In the code below, the returned user object is not nil, but not all members have their relevant values e.g.

> User id: 18, provider: nil, uid: nil, name: "newonenewone", oauth_token: nil, oauth_expires_at: nil, created_at: "2013-12-28
>   22:17:35", updated_at: "2013-12-28 22:17:35", email:
>   "newonenewone@newonenewone.com", encrypted_password:
>   "14972b4..."

But when checking if the user object is nil it returned true! So why this happens and how to fix it.

```
def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
 user = find_by_email(email)
 return nil if user.nil?
 return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Please walk through your code in the case when the user is not `nil` **but** the user does not have a password.  In that case, the `authenticate` method will return `nil`.  This happens because you are not handling any cases after the second `return` statement.  This results in a `nil` return by Ruby convention.

In other words, you may want to add code below:

```
def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
 user = find_by_email(email)
 return nil if user.nil?
 return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
 # TODO: handle case when !user.nil? && !user.has_password?
end
```

Comment: I think this can handle that 
( user && user.has_password?(submitted_password) ) ? user : nil

Comment: Yes, that will be exactly equivalent to what you have. i.e. It will behave the same, still returning `nil` when the submitted password doesn't match.

Comment: OPS, I misunderstood this. the authenticate method will not be called if the password is nil I added this line return user if !user.nil? && !user.has_password?(submitted_password) but it will make the method to return the user even if the password didn't match, so I am still in trouble here.

Comment: I'm not following you. Please post your new code and the use case required to make it fail.